# bring edit and delete buttons in gridview in one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I want to bring Edit and delete buttons in gridview in one column.

Currently it is:

[image]

Code For Edit and Delete Button:

```
 <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center">
                                  <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LBUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                                        CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LBCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                        CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LBEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                        CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>


                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ShowHeader="False">

                                  <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Bind("SrNo") %>' CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="10%" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

To bring Edit and Delete in one column i made following changes:

```
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign ="Center">
                                  <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LBUpdate" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                                        CommandName="Update" Text="Update"></asp:LinkButton>
                                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LBCancel" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                        CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </EditItemTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LBEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                        CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                              <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                                        CommandArgument='<%# Bind("SrNo") %>' CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
                                </ItemTemplate>

                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

But now with this code i am unable to find Edit button. Only delete button is present.

Its as follows:

[image]

Please help me i wanted to take Edit and deelete buttons in one column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined two `ItemTemplate`s, but only the last one is being picked up by the ASP.NET engine. Here is the correct way to declare this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LBEdit" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
        CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit"></asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton4" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
        CommandArgument='<%# Bind("SrNo") %>' CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: ohh, thanx, i got the mistake